# Java Script - Regular Expression matching a word in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a match in a string with JavaScript. I want to work with the RegEx function.

My example (what I have tried):

```
var str = "hello.you"; 
var patt1 = '\\b' + str + '\\b';
var result = str.match(patt1);
```

But this does not give me the result which I except. I just want to print "you".

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect `you` when you use `/\bhello.you\b/` regex against `hello.you` string? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thx for your answer. I just wanted to show what I have tried so far. I want to print the word "you" in the string "hello.you" with Regex @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Lia You don't need regex for that. Just return the word "you" and you're done. Unless there are different variations of that string? In that case you really should elaborate on what you expect if the string is not "hello.you". Do you want to get everything after the dot? What if there is more than one dot? Be specific.

Comment: Then use `result = str.match(/\.(\w+)/)[1]`. Or `str.match(/\.([^.]+)/)[1]`. Or just `str.split('.')[1]`

Comment: Thank you that works fine !! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Note it won't work in case of `Привет.Петя` (=Russian for `Hello.Peter`) because `\w` does not match non-ASCII letters and digits.

Comment: Want me to post an answer? I am unsure of what kind of answer you really need here.

Answer (score 0):

So you jumped right into a pretty advanced regex topic. You sort of want to do a lookahead (the word AFTER a given boundary character). The following will get you there:

```js
let str = "hello.you",
    myRegex = /(?<=\.)\w+/;
    
let theWord = str.match(myRegex);
console.log(theWord[0]);
```

... And what that does, is uses (?<=.) to indicate "something that comes after a period", followed by \w+ to indicate a word.

I'd recommend using a regex tester, and build from that. I use https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Running the code snippet returns `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group` when using Firefox.

Comment: Wondering if FireFox is supporting lookaheads/lookbehinds yet.